# how to create a test case to follow a process on my laptop

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, linux-mint

I am a newbie and NEED advice/instruction on how to find out what process is bugging down the CPU,MEM and DISK.

have been reading on how to follow process using htop,ps, pstree and strace however, I would like to create a test case (create a loop program that writes to disk) for me to follow on my laptop the CPU usage, MEM and ,more importantly, how to recognize when it is writing to disk.

so far I've got this little loop program I found here and I can see it on Htop,ps,strace but need help figuring out how tho trace it thru the cpu, mem, and disk usage.

NB-PC:~$ cat script/infinite_loop.sh

while true;do echo -n;done

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't got what you wanted. You already mentioned *htop* — so you can simply leave only you single app with *filter* option *(press «F4» inside the htop)*.

Comment: I want to learn how to follow any program running thru cpu,disk writing...like, IF I want to find out a certain program is IO bound or cpu is idle and such things...but I do not have a real life application to simulate and analyse . any suggestions on an example on how to follow a process thru so I can learn by this example?

Comment: I guess, I am looking for a small program that writes to disk and leaves cpu idle so I can detect it for learning purposes. I don't know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Well, if you really want it, you can just modify your script to be like `while true;do echo "Hello everypony" > ./foo;done` — this way you permanently writing the words into the file *foo*. The `>` as opposed to `>>` overwrites the file on every loop — i.e. you don't have to worry that the file quickly overcome a couple terabytes.

Comment: ok, I will try this edit. I hope to be able to capture the flow going thru and watching/learn how to figure out a bound process. thanks!

Comment: But I just thought — I am frankly don't know, would it do IO, or no. See: Linux is happy to cache everything it can, and in the particular case it could just cache out this permanent overwriting a single text line. Then you will see the CPU being busy, but no IO. In such a case you may want to change the `>` to `>>` in the script, but beware that the file *(depending on you hard drive speed, tho)* can grow up quickly.

Comment: I was able to use the Dstat cmmand and saw the activity on the disk and also did a iostat. the status of the drive went to "D" while I had the script running.

Comment: I will use the >> now and see what the difference is... and what the disk and cpu are doing. will give you an update on what I find. thanks!